# Cannot connect Bluetooth via Multipeer Connectivity

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, bluetooth, multipeer-connectivity

Swift 3.0

I can share data from iPhone to iPhone over Wifi using Multipeer Connectivity but not over Bluetooth, and it looks to me that the Wifi is unstable.  
The Wifi will connect half of the time and the Bluetooth will see the peers but will not connect.  
What would be the best way to connect an IPhone to an iPhone an a IPhone to any other type of Phone locally.  An example is as in no Internet or no Wifi.  
I also will eventually be sending data to a server, and receiving data from that server.

This would give me 3 connection choices:

1.Private using   (Bluetooth)?  Standing side-by-side
  
2.Semi Private using   (Wifi)  office to office
  
3.Public using   (Internet)  worldwide


 Is this code wrong for Bluetooth connection?

```
import UIKit
import MultipeerConnectivity



class ViewController: UIViewController, MCSessionDelegate, MCBrowserViewControllerDelegate,  UINavigationControllerDelegate , UIImagePickerControllerDelegate{



//MARK: - Variables
var myDictionary:NSDictionary = [:]

//Variables for Peer to Peer.
var browser   : MCBrowserViewController!
var assistant : MCAdvertiserAssistant!
var session   : MCSession!
var peerID    : MCPeerID!

//Variables for Peer to Peer.
let imagePicker  = UIImagePickerController()
var imageDataVar: NSData!



//MARK: - Labels
@IBOutlet weak var firstNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lastNameLabel:  UILabel!

//MARK: - TextFields
@IBOutlet weak var fistNameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var lastNameTextField: UITextField!

//MARK: - Outlets

@IBOutlet weak var contactImageView: UIImageView!

//MARK: - Buttons
@IBAction func openPortButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    self.present(self.browser, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func sendButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    sendInfo()
}

@IBAction func getImage(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    chooseImageContact()
}



//MARK: - ViewDidLoad
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadPeerToPeer()
}


//MARK: - Functions
func sendInfo() {
    if self.session.connectedPeers.count > 0 {
        let firstNameVar = fistNameTextField.text!
        let lastNameVar = lastNameTextField.text!
            myDictionary = ["itemA" : "\(firstNameVar)", "itemB" : "\(lastNameVar)", "itemC" : imageDataVar]
        do {
            let data =  NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: myDictionary)
            try self.session.send(data, toPeers: self.session.connectedPeers, with: MCSessionSendDataMode.unreliable)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Send error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            present(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}


// Called when a peer sends an NSData to us
func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive data: Data, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {

    // This needs to run on the main queue
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.myDictionary = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as! NSDictionary

        self.firstNameLabel.text    = self.myDictionary.value(forKey: "itemA") as? String
        self.lastNameLabel.text     = self.myDictionary.value(forKey: "itemB") as? String
        let image                   = self.myDictionary.value(forKey: "itemC") as? NSData
        let newContactImage:UIImage = UIImage(data: image! as Data)!
        let smallPicture            = self.scaleContactImageWith(newContactImage, newSize: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
        var sizeOfImage:CGRect      = self.contactImageView.frame
            sizeOfImage.size        = smallPicture.size
        self.contactImageView.frame = sizeOfImage
        self.contactImageView.image = smallPicture
    }
}


func browserViewControllerDidFinish(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func browserViewControllerWasCancelled(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func browserViewController(_ browserViewController: MCBrowserViewController, shouldPresentNearbyPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withDiscoveryInfo info: [String : String]?) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func session(_ session: MCSession, peer peerID: MCPeerID, didChange state: MCSessionState) {
    switch state {
    case MCSessionState.connected:
        print("Connected: \(peerID.displayName)")
    case MCSessionState.connecting:
        print("Connecting: \(peerID.displayName)")
    case MCSessionState.notConnected:
        print("Not Connected: \(peerID.displayName)")
    }
}

func session(_ session: MCSession, didStartReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, with progress: Progress) {
}
func session(_ session: MCSession, didFinishReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, at localURL: URL, withError error: Error?) {
}
func session(_ session: MCSession, didReceive stream: InputStream, withName streamName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}



func loadPeerToPeer(){
    self.peerID  = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.current.name)
    self.session = MCSession(peer: peerID, securityIdentity: nil, encryptionPreference: .required)
    self.session = MCSession(peer: self.peerID)
    self.session.delegate = self
    self.assistant = MCAdvertiserAssistant(serviceType:"VBC-ShareCard", discoveryInfo:nil, session:self.session)
    self.assistant.start()
    self.browser = MCBrowserViewController(serviceType: "VBC-ShareCard", session: self.session)
    self.browser.delegate = self
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}


// Picking the image
func chooseImageContact(){
    let imagePicker            = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate   = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
    self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


//Scalling the image
func scaleContactImageWith(_ image:UIImage, newSize:CGSize)->UIImage{
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0)
        image.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height))
    let newContactImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newContactImage
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    //This gets the Contact image inside the imagePickerController
    let pickedImage:UIImage     = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    let smallPicture            = scaleContactImageWith(pickedImage, newSize: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
    var sizeOfImage:CGRect      = contactImageView.frame
        sizeOfImage.size        = smallPicture.size
        contactImageView.frame  = sizeOfImage
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        contactImageView.image  = smallPicture as UIImage
    let test : Data             = UIImagePNGRepresentation(smallPicture)!
        imageDataVar            = test as NSData!
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bluetooth issue is in the testing of the Bluetooth connection not the code.
I have found that in Swift 3.0 (which I am running) you cannot turn off Wifi and do the test you have to go into the Setting> Wi-Fi  then choose the Wi-Fi/Network your connected to. Then select  Forget This Network.

Even though you have no Wi-Fi/Network now the WiFi itself and Bluetooth must be turned on.

Comment: I had the same issue and now this solution works for me. Do you know why Bluetooth does not work when Wifi is off, and is there a way to make it work in code?

Comment: I now have a new i phone8 and when I ran a test.
i phone8 wifi off and i phone5 wifi on it works.
i phone5 wifi off and i phone8 wifi on it will not works.
Apple may have fix/changed this in the update I don't know.
Check for wifi connection

Answer (score 0):

I found this to get the wi-fi ID.
This may work for you. If there is an ID do somthing else if nil do somthing.

```
func getWiFiSsid() -> String? {
    var ssid: String?
    if let interfaces = CNCopySupportedInterfaces() as NSArray? {
        for interface in interfaces {
            if let interfaceInfo = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(interface as! CFString) as NSDictionary? {
                ssid = interfaceInfo[kCNNetworkInfoKeySSID as String] as? String
                break
            }
        }
    }
    print(ssid as Any, "This is/is not the ssid" as Any)
    return ssid
}
```